# Rebase instead of fast forward

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I'm new to GIT and I can't figure out if my question already has an answer. Please read it carefully before marking it as duplicate.

I have a branch, let's call it `public`, which is pushed and in sync with `origin`. At one point, I create another branch, `private`, which pops out of `public`, because I want to do a lot of work which I want to remain secret. So I only work on `private` and I do, let's say, 10 commits, until I finally arrive to a state which can be made public.

Now, I obviously **don't want to do a fast-forward merge** of `public` because all the intermediary commits would appear on the remote server.
How can I do a `rebase` given that the `public` branch has not diverged from the point where `private` was created.

Clearly, I want to create a new commit on the `public` branch that contains all the modifications from the 10 `private` commits. I know that translates into a `rebase`, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `git rebase -i`and select `squash`for your 10 commits so you'll only have one big commit rebased on your public branch.

When using -i with rebase, you'll get a text editor where you can choose how each commit will be rebased (or if it will berebased at all). Squash is the option that allow you to integrate multiple commits in a single one with this kind of syntax (from github doc, link below) :

```
pick 1fc6c95 Patch A
pick 6b2481b Patch B
squash dd1475d something I want to split
squash c619268 A fix for Patch B
squash fa39187 something to add to patch A
squash 4ca2acc i cant' typ goods
squash 7b36971 something to move before patch B
```

This will rebase 2 commits : "Patch A" will be verbatim will "Patch B" will include the changes from the next "squashed" commits.

Please see "Interactive Rebasing" in [reference](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or the nice [github doc page](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/) for details.

Comment: What do you mean by "select `squash`"?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the fact that `public` is *tracking* a remote branch that lives on `origin` does not mean that the local branch `public` is equivalent to the remote branch `origin/public`.

Because of git's distributed nature, you can make a bunch of commits on your local `public` branch without anything making it to the server, as long as you do not push.

With respect to what you are trying to do given the current state of your system, here are some detailed steps, assuming you do not care about keeping your original 10 commits.

1. Begin interactive rebase against the current state of the remote server.

   ```
   git checkout private
   git rebase -i origin/public
   ```
2. An editor will pop up. The specific editor will depend on the platform and the environmental variable settings. Inside this editor, you will see the hashes of your 10 commits, with the word "pick" in the left hand column. For the first row, keep `pick`. For the subsequent rows, replace `pick` with `squash`. Save the file and quit the editor.
3. At this point, `git` will have merged the 10 commits into a single commit, so we can merge into `public` and push.

   ```
   git checkout public
   git merge private
   git push
   ```

---

If you wanted to keep your original 10 commits on the local `private` branch, you can instead do a fast-forward merge onto the local `public` branch and rebase there instead.

```
git checkout public
git merge private
git rebase -i origin/public
# Do the same rebase steps as above
git push
```

Comment: Thank you for the final tip, that may be useful to me in the future. Right now, I have just created a new private branch and rebased that, thus making sure I keep my 10 commits on the original private branch, which remains unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

To be exact, creating a new commit on `public` that contains the modifications from `private` does not call for `rebase`. It calls for `merge`.

Rebasing to squash together the commits of `private` before seems to be what you want, you keep a branch and a merge commit.

However since you don't care about the detailed history of your `private` branch, you could just as well:

```
$ git checkout public
$ git merge --squash private
$ git commit
```

The index is first updated with the content of `private`, and you can make a single commit of it on top of `public`.

Comment: way simpler indeed ... didn't know about this syntax

Comment: Awesome. This is faster!